# Is there a way to auto set your Android Package Name?

Tags: android, package, naming

What I mean is, if I were to work for Google and I was making apps the naming convention of the package would be com.google.androidappname; Is there a way to auto-populate it with com.google instead of com.example.app name?

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Answer (score 0):

When you creating a new project whether is in eclipse or androi studio, the first screen of the new project wizard has package name propery which default is "com.example".

You can change that to whatever you want. Convention is you reverse domain ex. com.facebook.something.else.if.you.want, com.twitter.app.

But it doesn't matter what you put, as long as doesn't conflict with some other app when you publish it on the play market.